# The "beforeheading" counterpart of \@afterheading

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

Suppose that for ransom reasons (in my case, because my document was converted from XML) I want to typeset all headings manually. Then I could do something like

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

{\samepage\vspace*{2\baselineskip}\centering%
Chapter 1\\
\Large The beginning of everything
\vspace*{\baselineskip}

}
\makeatletter\@afterheading\makeatother

\noindent Some text.
\end{document}
```

Well, `\@afterheading` does a nice job of making sure that there must not *under any circumstances* be a page break after the heading. But I'm looking in vain for a `\@beforeheading` command that tells LaTeX that it should consider breaking pages *before* the heading if the the alternative is to have the heading appear close to the bottom of the page. I experimented with using `\@startsection{chapter}{1}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{}*{}`, but I saw no effects. How does LaTeX normally do that internally?

Comment: BTW, not sure if it's going to matter, but you shouldn't worry about table of contents. That's already implemented in my document. All that matters is to make the headings behave nicely.

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but if you are converting from XML why are these things not marked up as sections?

Comment: They are, kinda. Truth be told, the XML document is encoded in an awful way. But there is some structure: all headings are enclosed in `<chapter>` tags (on *all* section levels, including sections, subsections, etc.; so a section is a `<chapter>` within a `<chapter>`). Does that somehow make things easier?

Comment: But one of the things that are awful about it is that it typesets each heading manually. It doesn't use any standard settings like CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would almost certainly be better to generate

```
\section{The beginning of everything}
```

but otherwise remove the `\samepage` and add penalties before and after.

```
{\vspace{0pt plus 3\baselineskip}%
 \pagebreak[1]%
 \vspace{2\baselineskip plus -3\baselineskip}%
  \centering
Chapter 1\\*%
\Large The beginning of everything%

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\baselineskip}%

}
```

Comment: And remove `\@afterheading`, too?

Comment: @Gaussler no afterheading is mostly controlling the indentation and clubpenalties to control the first line of the following text, you want to keep that,

Comment: And is it then guaranteed that there are not going to appear pagebreaks between, say, "Chapter 1" and "The beginning of everything"? For that was why I inserted `\samepage` in the first place.

Comment: @Gaussler oh use `\\*`  to prevent a break there

Comment: Oops, just realised that I forgot to accept this answer. Sorry about that. :-)

Comment: shouldn't the second `\vspace` be starred, to ensure some extra blank lines on the top of a page?

Comment: @Gaussler not as written (as it could be negative) It's written assuming th\t it will be discarded at a break.

Comment: What if I *did* want some space at the top of the new page if the page was broken? That is fairly common with new chapters.

Comment: @Gaussler you could add an additional `\vspace*`

Comment: BTW, what is the point of this seemlingly strange choice of negative and positive lengths? Why not just `\vspace{2\baselineskip}`?